# Is there a way to take a screenshot from a specific area with Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping this website (with Selenium) that is basically a database with exam questions. I need to take a screenshot of each question (and answers). Is there a way to screenshot ONLY the question and answers and not the whole page?

So far I've tried using `screenshot_as_png` but no success.

Some questions are very long and don't fit on the screen. This is why I don't even know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible. An alternative is also accepted. Perhaps a way I could extract the whole question (including the images) would solve the problem for me.

This is the link: https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes?discipline_ids%5B%5D=13&discipline_ids%5B%5D=16&discipline_ids%5B%5D=39&discipline_ids%5B%5D=46&discipline_ids%5B%5D=56&discipline_ids%5B%5D=57&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=1&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=2&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=5&scholarity_ids%5B%5D=1&scholarity_ids%5B%5D=2

Example: I'm able to locate a div with a given question. How can I screenshot only the content of the question?

Comment: I don't think taking a screenshot and then cropping the image would work on this case.

Comment: You may be better off extracting the text of the question and answer then rendering that.

Comment: That was my first thought too. But how can I extract a text with images? (Ex: [text] [text] [text] [text] [IMAGE] [text] [text] [text])